# vba excel code editing

Tags: vba, excel

I've compiled a code by patching several code snippets that I could find online (Which does work).
With very limited knowledge on VBA, I'm not able to tweak it further to make it run more efficiently. It takes a while to run if there are too many rows in the worksheet.

I need the code to run in an excel file which is regularly created by Acrobat 10 from a pdf file. A sheet "Table 1" is automatically created and the whole data is tables. The code that I have below, attempts to extract parts of the table and create a new output on a sheet "Result" in the same workbook. The code also  creates another sheet "Result2" for temporarily holding some data and then deletes the sheet.

Hoping that someone can please tidy up this code to work efficiently because I sometimes need to work with sheets having about 15000 rows.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DefectDescription()
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim strValue As String
Dim lngRowOutput As Long
Sheets.Add.Name = "Result"
Sheets("Result").Move After:=Sheets("Table 1")
' where does the data end in Sheet(Table 1)
lngLastRow = Sheets("Table 1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If lngLastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
' Clear down sheet (Result), assume we have column headings in row 1 we want  to keep
Sheets("Result").Range("2:1048576").Clear

lngRowOutput = 2 ' where are we going to write the values to in Sheet(Result) when we find a "Defect Description" phrase

For lngRow = 1 To lngLastRow
strValue = Sheets("Table 1").Cells(lngRow, 1).Value ' get value from column A
If InStr(1, strValue, "Defect Description", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' can we find "Defect Description :" in the text
Sheets("Table 1").Rows(lngRow).Offset(2, 0).Copy
Sheets("Result").Rows(lngRowOutput).PasteSpecial
       lngRowOutput = lngRowOutput + 1
End If
Next lngRow
Call FinalAction
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Result2").Delete
With Sheets("Result")
Sheets("Result").Cells.UnMerge
End With      
'the below lines of code is used to delete blank columns after unmerging cells
Sheets("Result").Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Result").Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Result").Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Result").Columns(6).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
Sub FinalAction()
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim strValue As String
Dim lngRowOutput As Long
Sheets.Add.Name = "Result2"
' where does the data end in Sheet(Table 1)
lngLastRow = Sheets("Table 1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If lngLastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
' Clear down sheet (Result2), assume we have column headings in row 1 we want to keep
Sheets("Result2").Range("2:1048576").Clear
lngRowOutput = 2 ' where are we going to write the values to in Sheet(Result2)   when we find a "Final Action" phrase
For lngRow = 1 To lngLastRow
strValue = Sheets("Table 1").Cells(lngRow, 1).Value ' get value from column A
If InStr(1, strValue, "Final Action", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' can we find "Defect Description :" in the text
Sheets("Table 1").Rows(lngRow).Offset(2, 0).Copy
Sheets("Result2").Rows(lngRowOutput).PasteSpecial
lngRowOutput = lngRowOutput + 1
End If
Next lngRow
With Worksheets("Result2")
.Range("A1:M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Copy     Destination:=Sheets("Result").Range("N1")
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be twice faster (one loop in place of 2).
I just integrated the relevant part of FinalAction sub into DefectDescription, without an extract of original data and expected output, that's quite hard to do more. Feel free to comment if there's unclear or not enough commented parts.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DefectDescription()
  Dim lngLastRow As Long
  Dim lngRow As Long
  Dim strValue As String
  Dim lngRowOutput As Long

  Sheets.Add.Name = "Result"
  Sheets.Add.Name = "Result2"
  Sheets("Result").Move After:=Sheets("Table 1")

  ' where does the data end in Sheet(Table 1)
  lngLastRow = Sheets("Table 1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
  If lngLastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data

  ' Clear down sheet (Result), assume we have column headings in row 1 we want  to keep
  Sheets("Result").Range("2:1048576").Clear
  Sheets("Result2").Range("2:1048576").Clear

  lngRowOutput1 = 2 ' where are we going to write the values to in Sheet(Result) when we find a "Defect Description" phrase
  lngRowOutput2 = 2 ' same for result2

  For lngRow = 1 To lngLastRow
    strValue = Sheets("Table 1").Cells(lngRow, 1).Value ' get value from column A
    Sheets("Table 1").Rows(lngRow).Offset(2, 0).Copy
    If InStr(1, strValue, "Defect Description", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' can we find "Defect Description :" in the text
      Sheets("Result").Rows(lngRowOutput1).PasteSpecial
      lngRowOutput1 = lngRowOutput1 + 1
    End If
    If InStr(1, strValue, "Final Action", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      Sheets("Result2").Rows(lngRowOutput2).PasteSpecial
      lngRowOutput2 = lngRowOutput2 + 1
    End If
  Next lngRow

  With Worksheets("Result2")
    .Range("A1:M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Range("N1")
  End With

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Sheets("Result2").Delete
  With Sheets("Result")
    Sheets("Result").Cells.UnMerge
  End With

  'the below lines of code is used to delete blank columns after unmerging cells
  Sheets("Result").Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
  Sheets("Result").Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
  Sheets("Result").Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
  Sheets("Result").Columns(6).EntireColumn.Delete
  Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
  Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
  Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
  Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
  Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
  Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
  Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
  Sheets("Result").Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Tensibai. The code does not run, it gives an error "next without a for statement". I can't seem to figure it as there is a "for" statement.. any ideas?

Comment: I forgot a End IF, Editing

Comment: Thank you again, it works now. I will test it on a bigger file later and see how it goes.

Comment: If you can give a sample input and expected output, there's maybe another way to do it.

Comment: I've posted the same on http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=193907 If you have a login, you can access the sample files that I have uploaded, else i can email the files if u can leave your ID. Thank you for your time again.

Comment: Sorry but I don't wish to create another account to just download a sample file, could you share the xlsx by another way ? (with a link in the question for example)